# Inserting XML into SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql, xml, sql-server-2008, encoding

I having trouble inserting a XML into SQL Server 2008. My Java Application creates a XML and trying to insert that into a Column of type "XML" under SQL Server 2008.

It's throwing error

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:390)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:322)
```

This is the XML declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
```

I am not sure what XML encoding SQL Server 2008 expects to work fine.

Can anyone suggest what should I try to resolve this?

Comment: How did you try to insert the XML exactly? Try to pass the XML content as nvarchar maybe

Comment: We are using JDBC to insert XML into table which has a column of dat type XML

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encoding to "UTF-8". 
Below is the link to the example from Microsoft website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms191184.aspx

Comment: So you mean, it's required that XML should be UTF-8 encoded for XML type columns?